# TkInter get width of specific text

Tags: python, tkinter, width, tkinter-label

Is there a way to find out what width a `Label` would be for a given text and font, *without* having to add it to the graphical elements currently being displayed.

I need to get the information without any effect on the GUI, however momentary that effect may be. And, in any case, packing appears to work in a top-down fashion, meaning that controls may expand to fill others higher in the hierarchy but I can't get them to adjust those higher to allow for their actual size.

I'm more used to QML where I can just give an off-screen element the text and font details then just read out the bounding box.

Does anyone know how to do something similar in Tkinter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the `Label` without calling `pack() / grid() / place()`, then call `winfo_reqwidth()` and `winfo_reqheight()` on the label to get its size.